# SQL Server 2008 IN ALL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a easy way to do an IN ALL command in SQL?

For example if I had:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE col IN (1,2)
```

this is really the same as:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE col = 1 OR col = 2
```

but what I really want is:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE col = 1 AND col = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id
FROM [table]
WHERE col IN (1,2) 
group by id
having count(distinct col) = 2
```

Comment: His second query would never return any records would it?

Comment: @Abe An example of what I think is being asked is, "show me all the companies that have addresses in both Dallas and Austin".